# All programs are closed after lid is closed

Tags: unity, laptop, power-management, 15.10, lid

I have Lenovo Y570 with Ubuntu 15.10 installed on it. Whenever I close the lid and then open it, I see the log-in screen, and if I type in my password, I find that all my programs from last session are closed and it's like a fresh new session. But if I choose to suspend the laptop manually, this problem doesn't happen - it suspends and resumes normally.

I am using Unity shell (the one that comes with stock Ubuntu) and I don't think I've installed anything additional that could interfere with this process.

I have reconfigured the power settings to not to do anything when the lid is closed, but this still happens.

Oh and BTW, here goes the logs of what happens around opening and closing of the lid:

[image: print-screen-1]
[image: print-screen-2]

And here goes the output of `lspci`:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3981
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 555M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3981
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: Your system is set up to poweroff on lid close. Check System Settings -> Power options.

Comment: @Pilot6 no, it's configured to suspend after closing lid.

Comment: Try to go into bios and see what setting on lid close is there.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've looked at this laptop's bios many times. It doesn't have any settings for lid, it has almost no settings at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Please include textual data as text (not images). File or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more accessible and searchable that way. You can select and copy terminal content with the mouse cursor or see [How can I easily share the output of a command or a text file with others?](/q/152371/175814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot after the driver is installed.

Comment: Looks like it worked, thx